# Importing a data frame from CSV file using Pandas with column name having spaces

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am trying to import a data frame from a `.csv` file which contains Per Capita Income. Moreover, in the above mentioned file the column name is **Per Capita Income (US$)**, however when I try to import it with the same name it gives me a syntax error, which is quite obvious. However, when I remove spaces from the column name in the subject `.csv` file it works fine - as per the below code`df.percapita`; as I have changed it from **Per Capita Income (US$)** to **percapita**. What could I possibly do to use the same column name as mentioned in the given file to import the required data frame.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model

df = pd.read_csv("/xxxx/xxxx/Desktop/Python/Machine Learning/Linear Regression/PortugalIncome.csv")

reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(df[['year']], df.percapita)
reg.predict(np.array([2017]).reshape(1,1))

y = reg.coef_*2016+reg.intercept_

print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly access the column by:

```
df["Per Capita Income (US$)"]
```

instead of df.percapita